# What has your experience been like developing for the Netbeans platform for cross platform development?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, cross-platform

I am familiar with the Netbeans IDE, but I want to know about people's experience with using Netbeans as a development platform (i.e. using its prebuilt modules for fast gui development).  I have a program that I want to write, and I am thinking about using this platform.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of cross-platform development? I have had a good experience using Netbeans for cross-platform PHP development.

In my experience, Netbeans has excellent support for code highlighting and identifying function/object names, etc. I tried using both Eclipse and Netbeans for editing HTML/CSS/Javascript and (to my surprize) found Netbeans' editor provides a much better  experience. It is also handy that the IDE will automatically upload code to a remote site using FTP or SFTP, and that it supports remote debugging with XDebug. For the most part I have been happy with the tool.  The only thing I do not like about Netbeans is that sometimes the IDE is unresponsive when typing text - this may be a resource issue as when I restart the IDE everything works great again. Anyway, this is a minor gripe but it can certainly be frustrating.

Comment: I am actually referring to using the Netbeans platform to use its own components to make a gui program fast.